# Disabling autocomplete suggestions in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, autocomplete, react-native-paper

I've looked around quite a bit and can't seem to find an elegant solution to this. I basically need to disable any kind of suggestions that show up above the keyboard in both `Android` and `iOS`. So far, the solutions I've tried seem to work the `iOS` simulator at least, but not on `Android`.

I've tried the following:

1. For pure React Native, setting `autoCorrect={false}`, `spellCheck={false}` and `autoComplete="off"`
2. For Native `Android`, `importantForAutofill="no"` or:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

In the `onCreate(...)` method of `MainActivity`.

For `Android`, is there any way to disable these suggestions completely? Perhaps some configuration in the `AndroidManifest` or `styles`? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I'm using the `TextInput` from the `react-native-paper` library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `keyboardType="visible-password"` ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd been using that. Forgot to mention that I'm using the `TextInput` from the `react-native-paper` library. I also had to use the `textContentType="password"` for it to work properly.